# How to build a script which can Get Content periodically from internet and save it to every new csv file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, web-scraping

I am a beginner to PowerShell and thinking of developing a scraping tool for a dynamic webpage using PowerShell.

***IDEA:***

I tried 'Invoke-WebRequest' for scraping a free scraping site 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/'
After Scraping, ('For Loop, (Get-content | Format-Table) and Export-CSV' commands will be used) which will create a new .csv file in new folder and save the content into that file.

**Difficulty 1**: Tried to scrape 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/' using 'Invoke-WebRequest', but I did not find any strings of Quotes. To me it looks like it just returned the Formatting code

Output :

```
 StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html lang="en">
                    <head>
                        <meta charset="UTF-8">
                        <title>Quotes to Scrape</title>
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap.min.css">
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/m...
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Connection: keep-alive
                    Vary: Accept-Encoding
                    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
                    Content-Length: 11053
                    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
                    Date: Sat...
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[Connection, keep-alive], [Vary, Accept-Encoding], [Strict-Transport-Security, max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains], [Content-Length,
                    11053]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {@{innerHTML=Quotes to Scrape; innerText=Quotes to Scrape; outerHTML=<A style="TEXT-DECORATION: none" href="/">Quotes to Scrape</A>;
                    outerText=Quotes to Scrape; tagName=A; style=TEXT-DECORATION: none; href=/}, @{innerHTML=Login; innerText=Login; outerHTML=<A
                    href="/login">Login</A>; outerText=Login; tagName=A; href=/login}, @{innerHTML=(about); innerText=(about); outerHTML=<A
                    href="/author/Albert-Einstein">(about)</A>; outerText=(about); tagName=A; href=/author/Albert-Einstein}, @{innerHTML=change;
                    innerText=change; outerHTML=<A class=tag href="/tag/change/page/1/">change</A>; outerText=change; tagName=A; class=tag;
                    href=/tag/change/page/1/}...}
ParsedHtml        : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
RawContentLength  : 11053
```

**Difficulty 2:**

Full code Working:

```
#1. Creating an array of Folders using For Loop 
for ($i = 1; $i -lt 6; $i++){
    $folders = New-Item -Path "C:\Users\Henry\PowerShellscripts\Project8\May 1$i" -ItemType Directory
    #2. Using For Each Loop to create QuotestoStore.csv inside them 
    foreach($sample in $folders) {
        Add-Content -Path "$sample\QuotestoStore.csv" -Value Invoke-WebRequest 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/'
        Write-Host "$sample saved."
    }
}
```

**Error Messages:**

```
Add-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 
'https://quotes.toscrape.com/'.
At line:6 char:9
+         Add-Content -Path "$sample\QuotestoStore.csv" -Value Invoke-W ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddConten 
   tCommand
```

**Doubt 1: As we see in (Difficulty 1) the Web Formatting code is returned instead of the values or the Text in the webpage, So Which Syntax should I use to get values of quotes from webpage 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/'  ??

Doubt 2: (Add-Content -Path "$sample\QuotestoStore.csv" -Value Invoke-WebRequest 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/')
Can I include (Invoke-WebRequest 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/) command in -Value Parameter??... If not how to create a function and insert that here, to export the content to csv.??

Doubt 3: Can we add a time variable ($stop = '12:52:30') and create the following Code: ??**

```
    [datetime] $stop = '12:52:30'

Do{
    for ($i = 1; $i -lt 6; $i++){
        $folders = New-Item -Path "C:\Users\Henry\PowerShellscripts\Project8\May 1$i" -ItemType Directory
        #2. Using For Each Loop to create QuotestoStore.csv inside them 
        foreach($sample in $folders) {
            Add-Content -Path "$sample\QuotestoStore.csv" -Value Invoke-WebRequest 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/'
            Write-Host "$sample saved."
        }
    }
}Until((Get-Date) -ge $stop)
```

Please Guide me !!

Thank you!!

Comment: Yes to your 2nd question in your second example. Most queries are harmless, why not "just do it"?(:

Comment: Main objective is to import data from webpage and store it in csv.. rest features will only work if the ( import,format & export-csv ) code works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It of course all depends on what you would like to capture from the quotes on that page, but I could imaging doing something like this (daily ?)

```
# create the target directory including the date like 'May 22'
$destination = 'C:\Users\Henry\PowerShellscripts\Project8\{0:MMM dd}'-f (Get-Date)
$null        = New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory -Force
$outFile     = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath 'QuotestoStore.csv'

$url = 'https://quotes.toscrape.com'
$req =  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Get

if ($req.StatusCode -ne 200) {
    Write-Warning "Error: Website returned statuscode $($req.StatusCode)"
}
else {
    $req.ParsedHtml.getElementsByClassName('quote') | ForEach-Object {
        $relativeLink = $_.getElementsByTagName('span')[1].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href -replace 'about:/'
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Quote  = $_.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].innerText -replace '[“”]'                       # quotes; remove the curly quotes
            Author = $_.getElementsByClassName('author')[0].innerText                                     # name of the author
            About  = '{0}/{1}' -f $url, $relativeLink                                                     # link to author page
            Tags   = $_.getElementsByClassName('tags')[0].getElementsByClassName('keywords')[0].content   # tag categories
            #or: Tags   = ($quotes[0].getElementsByClassName('tags')[0].getElementsByTagName('a') | ForEach-Object { $_.innerText }) -join ','
        }
    } | Export-Csv -Path $outFile -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Result would be a csv file:

```
"Quote";"Author";"About";"Tags"
"The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.";"Albert Einstein";"https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Albert-Einstein";"change,deep-thoughts,thinking,world"
"It is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities.";"J.K. Rowling";"https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/J-K-Rowling";"abilities,choices"
"There are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.";"Albert Einstein";"https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Albert-Einstein";"inspirational,life,live,miracle,miracles"
"The person, be it gentleman or lady, who has not pleasure in a good novel, must be intolerably stupid.";"Jane Austen";"https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Jane-Austen";"aliteracy,books,classic,humor"
"Imperfection is beauty, madness is genius and it's better to be absolutely ridiculous than absolutely boring.";"Marilyn Monroe";"https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Marilyn-Monroe";"be-yourself,inspirational"
"Try not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.";"Albert Einstein";"https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Albert-Einstein";"adulthood,success,value"
"It is better to be hated for what you are than to be loved for what you are not.";"Andr? Gide";"https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Andre-Gide";"life,love"
"I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.";"Thomas A. Edison";"https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Thomas-A-Edison";"edison,failure,inspirational,paraphrased"
"A woman is like a tea bag; you never know how strong it is until it's in hot water.";"Eleanor Roosevelt";"https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Eleanor-Roosevelt";"misattributed-eleanor-roosevelt"
"A day without sunshine is like, you know, night.";"Steve Martin";"https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Steve-Martin";"humor,obvious,simile"
```

---

Some explanation as per your comment:

1. Why the `-Force` switch on the New-Item cmdlet ?
   Without `-Force`, the cmdlet creates a new folder and returns a DirectoryInfo object of that new folder.
   However, if a folder with that name already existed, you wil receive an exception: *New-Item : An item with the specified name <path\to\the\folder> already exists.*.
   For good measure then you should first check if the folder exists or not with `Test-Path`, **OR** add the `-Force` switch, because then New-Item either creates the folder, or returns the DirectoryInfo object of the already existing folder without exceptions being thrown.
   Since I'm not interested in that returned DirectoryInfo object, I'm throwing that away by using `$null = New-Item ..`
2. Why `StatusCode -ne 200` ?
   A webrequest always returns a StatusCode telling you if the request was successful or not. There are a lot of them, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status). StatusCode 200 means 'OK', so then you can proceed with the rest of the code. If not, the answer displays a warning.
3. Why the `-UseCulture` switch on Export-Csv ?
   Many users tend to double-click a CSV file and expect their installed version of Excel to open it nicely with all fields in different columns.
   However, there are differences in the machine's locales (cultures) in the world. Without `-UseCulture`, Export-Csv will use the *comma* (`,`) as delimiter, but if you are in a country like me (The Netherlands), the machines default list separator is the *semi-colon* (`;`) as you can see in the example output. So in my case, if I don't specify the semi-colon as being the delimiter to use, Excel will make a mess of the file when double-clicking it. You can do that either by using parameter `-Delimiter ';'` if you know what Excel will understand, OR let the `-UseCulture` switch figure out what the current locale's ListSeparator is and use that.

   <sup>(It does that by using the character returned from `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator`)</sup>

Comment: Oh yes!! Awesome!! Only few queries if I may ask:
1. Why did you use '-Force' parameter used after -ItemType.??
I did not understand = The Force parameter lets you create a "FILE IN PROFILE PATH".
2. Not understood ( StatusCode -not equal to '200' ) ???
3. Not Understood " The UseCulture parameter uses the current culture's default list separator as the delimiter. The NoTypeInformation parameter removes the #TYPE information header from the CSV output "???

For the rest, I understood from Documentation... Thank you!

Comment: @user957744 I have added some explanation to the questions in your comment below the answer.

Comment: So simplified explanation !! understood !! HTTP response status codes  was completely new though...  Thank you for Detailed Explanation !!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get result as shown below then,

[image: Your response from web request in csv format]

User below code

```
$url = "https://quotes.toscrape.com/"

$webrequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -SessionVariable websession  -UseBasicParsing


$webrequest | Export-Csv "C:\Test.csv"
```

And if you want to schedule this process then  you can use windows scheduler in powershell(Register-ScheduledTask).